# Regular Expressions: about Greediness, Laziness and Substrings

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

`123322`

In theory, the *regex* `1.*2` should match the following:

- `12` (because `*` can be zero characters)
- `12332`
- `123322`

If I use the regex `1.*2` it matches `123322`.
Using `1.*?2`, it will match `12`.

**Is there a way to match `12332` too?**

The perfect thing would be to get **all possible matchess** in the string (no matter if one match **is substring** of another)

Comment: Are you sure that 1.*?2 matches 123322? I would have thought it only matches 12.

Comment: @Duniyadnd You're right. I fixed it.

Comment: What if you have `1` more than once in the string? If you want a simple `1.*2` pattern, you can simply find all positions of `1` and all positions of `2`, and choose all positions where one is bigger than the other - there's no reason for a regex in that case. My answer has a much more general approach to the problem, but I may have overcomplicated it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1(.*?2)*$
```

you will have multiple captures which you can concatenate to form all possible matches

see here:[regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=1%28.%2a%3f2%29%2a%24&i=123322)

click on 'table' and expand the captures tree

Comment: You're right. Don't know why I didn't think about it. I will have as matches as captures in Group 1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, unless there is something else added to the regex to clarify what it should do it will either be greedy or non-greedy.  There is no in-betweeny ;)

Answer (score 1):

You would need a separate expression for each case, depending on the number of twos you want to match:

```
1(.*?2){1}   #same as 1.*?2
1(.*?2){2}
1(.*?2){3}
...
```

Comment: Good idea. A simple loop will be enough, starting on 1 util it finds no matches ;)

Comment: Now that I see @Kobi answer, that will only work if every match is independent (eg: `12331232`: `1(.*?2){2}` should match `123312` and `1232`, but there's a common string in them: `12`). Of course, this is related to regular expresions in generl and not with your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this isn't possible. A regex matching engine isn't really designed to find overlapping matches. A quick solution is simply to check the pattern on all substrings manually:

```
string text = "1123322";
for (int start = 0; start < text.Length - 1; start++)
{
    for (int length = 0; length <= text.Length - start; length++)
    {
        string subString = text.Substring(start, length);
        if (Regex.IsMatch(subString, "^1.*2$"))
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}: {2}", start, start + length, subString);
    }
}
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/aNKnJ

Now, is it possible to get a whole-regex solution? Mostly, the answer is no. However, .Net does has a few tricks in its sleeve to help us: it allows variable length lookbehind, and allows each capturing group to remember all captures (most engines only return the last match of each group). Abusing these, we can simulate the same `for` loop inside the regex engine:

```
string text = "1123322!";
string allMatchesPattern = @"
(?<=^       # Starting at the local end position, look all the way to the back
(
  (?=(?<Here>1.*2\G))?  # on each position from the start until here (\G),
  .                     # *try* to match our pattern and capture it,
)*                      # but advance even if you fail to match it.
)
";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, allMatchesPattern,
            RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
foreach (Match endPosition in matches)
{
    foreach (Capture startPosition in endPosition.Groups["Here"].Captures)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}: {2}", startPosition.Index,
                          endPosition.Index - 1, startPosition.Value);
    }
}
```

Note that currently there's a small bug there - the engine doesn't try to match the last ending position ($), so you loose a few matches. For now, adding a `!` at the end of the string solves that issue.

working example: http://ideone.com/eB8Hb

Comment: That's valid too. In fact, that's very similar of what I'm doing in another part of my application, but the problem here is that it is `O(n^2*m)` (`m`: cost of `Regex.IsMatch`). `m` should be `O(n)` as it is an automate. There's no problem with `1123322`, but a text extracted from a file could be kind of big, and that's not really efficient, but is something I will need to do anyway if the client requests it :/

Comment: @Oscar - As you've said, I don't see how you can avoid the high complexity, assuming the regex is more complicate than you describe. You might do something specific to your regex to optimize it, but in worse case you create [all possible substrings](http://ideone.com/rH5dd), so you might as well iterate them: it doesn't make a difference, complexity wise, if that is done in your code or the regex engine. (also, I've mistaken your question to a *theoretical* question, not a practical one, I don't think I'll give my client that regex `:)`)