# PHP Regexp (PCRE) - Find a set of all substrings

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the following string, for example:

```
aaXXccYYeeXX_ZZkkYYmmXX_ZZnnXXooYYuuXX_ZZvv
```

How can I find all `XX.*YY.*ZZ` parts in the string? (possibly by using `preg_match()`)

- **XX** cc **YY** eeXX_ **ZZ**
- **XX** _*ZZkk **YY** mmXX*_ **ZZ**
- **XX** _*ZZnnXXoo **YY** uuXX*_ **ZZ**
- **XX** oo **YY** uuXX_ **ZZ**

Plus all longer matches, as:

- **XX** cc **YY** eeXX_ZZkkYYmmXX_ZZnnXXooYYuuXX_ **ZZ**

Comment: I've run into the same issue before. The problem is trying to find the overlapping ones, neither greedy or non-greedy work on their own. I'm no regex expert though.

Comment: Try some of the [RegexBuddy open source alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) for devising a match pattern.

Comment: This is similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163933/#5164444 , but that was using .Net, not PCRE.

Comment: I'll say what I've said in the other question - if the pattern is simple, or start/middle/end pattern aren't related (ie, `.*` between them, no back reference), you can find them independently by searching for all `XX`, all `YY` and all `ZZ`, and work out all combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank everybody for help.

My solution based on '[bobbogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470195/bobbogo)' solution. Thank you.

**Regular expression:**

```
(?=(XX.*?YY.*?ZZ))(?=(.*ZZ))
```

**Result (from RegexBuggy):**

```
1 XXccYYeeXX_ZZ     XXccYYeeXX_ZZkkYYmmXX_ZZnnXXooYYuuXX_ZZ
2 XX_ZZkkYYmmXX_ZZ      XX_ZZkkYYmmXX_ZZnnXXooYYuuXX_ZZ
3 XX_ZZnnXXooYYuuXX_ZZ  XX_ZZnnXXooYYuuXX_ZZ
4 XXooYYuuXX_ZZ     XXooYYuuXX_ZZ
```

Possible it can by more optimized? I am not big professional in regex.

Comment: Great to hear it is sorted. You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems quite straight forward at first glance (apologies if I am missing something). For the first part, use repeated matches of:

```
XX(.*?)YY(.*?)ZZ
```

For the longer match I suggest a separate match of:

```
XX(.*?)YY(.*)ZZ
```

**EDIT**

Aha! the patterns overlap (thanks folks). In this case, you will have to loop. Probably easiest to strip off any leading `.*?XX` before re-trying the match. In perl land you would use

```
while (/XX(.*?)YY(.*?)ZZ/) {
    print "[$1] [$2]\n";
    s/^.*?XX//;
}
```

If you are desperate for a single regex, then `m//g` in array context will come to your rescue. (Not sure what the corresponding php might look like.)

```
@a = /XX(?=(.*?YY.*?ZZ))/g;
```

The array `@a` will contain the overlapping strings, but with the initial `XX` stripped off.

Comment: You are missing something - which is expected, in my opinion, since the question is very confusing - the first and second results in the example are overlapping: `XXYYXX_ZZYYZZ` should yield *2* results: `XXYYXX_ZZ`  and `XX_ZZYYZZ`. You can get these with `(?=XX(.*?)YY(.*?)ZZ)`, but not for all possible lengths or all possibilities.