# Pattern Matcher Java - Finding All Substrings in a String

Tags: java, string, design-patterns, substring, matcher

Lets say I have a string "ATATATAT" and I want to use pattern and matcher to find all instances of "ATAT" in the given string. Why do I only get the two outside instances of "ATAT" and not the one in the middle? (AT**ATAT**AT) This is my code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public static void main (String args[]){
    String in = "ATATATAT";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ATAT");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Start: " + m.start() + " " + End: " + m.end());
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
Start: 0 End: 4
Start: 4 End: 8
```

Is it a problem with the regex?
Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5705217/3885376 .

Comment: From the Javadocs for `Matcher.find()`: "This method starts at ...the first character not matched by the previous match".